# Why my api json data can't read my properties from the loop and append the html data to the dom?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

Building a chat script, I am trying to fetch data from my api url. I tried doing a loop and for some reason the data can't read any of the properties.

JS

```
fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1geede')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(function(data) {

    headerDate (getWeekDay(getDateNow(data.data.conversationDate).getDay()) + ',' + getMonth(getDateNow(data.data.conversationDate).getMonth()) + getDateNow(data.data.conversationDate).getDate() + ', ' + ((getDateNow(data.data.conversationDate).getYear()) + 1900))

    const scope = data.data.messages;

    scope.forEach((i) => {

        let user = scope[i];

        if (user.username == 'Mygel van Trable') {
            user1( user.focused, user.image, user.message, getTimeStamp(user.timestamp), user.username);
        } else {
            user2( user.focused, user.image, user.message, getTimeStamp(user.timestamp), user.username);
        }

    console.log(user);

    });


});

const user1 = (focused, image, message, timestamp, username) =>  {

    $('.chat').innerHTML += 

    '<div class="chat-log user1">' +
    '<ul>' +
    '<li class="avatar">' +
    '<img src="'+ image + '" alt="Mygel van Trable">' +
    '</li>' +
    '<span class="chat_arrow_left"></span>' +
    '<li class="message">' +
    '<li class="message-box">' +
    '<p class="text"> ' + message + '</p>' +
    '<ul class="text-bottom">' +
    '<ul class="user-name">' + username + '</li>' +
    '<li class="timestamp">' +
    '<ul>' + 
    '<li class="clock-icon">' +
    '<img src="./img/clock.png" alt="clock-icon">' +
    '<li class="time">' + '<p>' + timestamp + '</p>' + '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>';



}

const user2 = (focused, image, message, timestamp, username) => {



    $('.chat').innerHTML += 

    '<div class="chat-log user1">' +
    '<ul>' +
    '<li class="avatar">' +
    '<img src="'+ image + '" alt="Mygel van Trable">' +
    '</li>' +
    '<span class="chat_arrow_left"></span>' +
    '<li class="message">' +
    '<li class="message-box">' +
    '<p class="text"> ' + message + '</p>' +
    '<ul class="text-bottom">' +
    '<li class="timestamp">' +
    '<ul>' + 
    '<li class="clock-icon">' +
    '<img src="./img/clock.png" alt="clock-icon">' +
    '<li class="time">' + '<p>' + timestamp + '</p>' + '</li>' +
    '<ul class="user-name">' + username + '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>';


}

const headerDate = (date) => {
    $('.header-date').innerHTML = date;
}


const getDateNow = (date) => {
    return new Date(date);
}

const getWeekDay = (week) => {

    let weekDays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

    return weekDays[week];
}

const getMonth = (month) => {
    let months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    return months[month];
}

const getTimeStamp = (time) => { 

    let timeNow = getDateNow(time);
    let hour = timeNow.getHours();
    let minute = timeNow.getMinutes();

    let day = 'AM';

    switch (time) {
        case hour > 11 : day = 'PM';
        break;
        case hour > 12 : hour = hour - 12;
        break;
        case hour == 0 : hour = 12;
        break;
        case hour < 10 : hour = "0" + hour;
        break;
        case minute < 10 : minute = "0" + minute;
        break;

    }

    const timeStamp = hour + ':' + minute + " " + 'day';

    return timeStamp;

}

const $ = (className) => {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(className);
}
```

I am having a hard time trying to loop through the array via the api json file and I am having no luck accomplishing it. The goal is to append the data to the html file.

Comment: can you please update the question with error you are facing, also your `console.log(user)` is out side the loop where the scope of user is not available.

Comment: @PrabhakarPandey It's updated. I thought my question clearly stated the errors already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scope.forEach((i) => {
    let user = scope[i];   <-- Wrong
});
```

this is wrong, the "i" is not the index but the actual object in the array.

```
scope.forEach((i) => {
  let user = i
});
```

this can be done in other ways to

```
for (const user of scope) {...}
```

or

```
for(let i = o ; i<scope.length; i++} {const user = scope[i] ...}
```